# Facade Pattern, is this ok?

Tags: facade

I have two servers that I will be connecting to from one client. For each server, I will be doing an ftp "put" and a "rm".

Should I build one facade, and have an interface like this:

```
void putFileOnServer1(String file)
void putFileOnServer2(String file)
void removeFromServer1(String file)
void removeFromServer2(String file)
```

And, should the facade handle all the establishing of the connections and disconnecting?
If so, should it use a factory to do so?

Comment: Are you trying to pick patterns to wedge into your design, or are you trying to understand what patterns are common when designing a particular solution?  The former results in badly designed solutions while the second probably needs more details of what problems you're trying to solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two methods, PutFileOnServer and RemoveFromServer. Which server you are putting or removing from should be part of the abstraction.

Comment: I don't see, how would I tell the facade which server i want to put the file?

Comment: To be honest, if you only have 2 servers and they are both FTP, you should have one class, and two instances of that class differing by FTP settings. You shouldn't create a class for each FTP server if they only differ by FTP settings.

Comment: thanks, to learn, what would you do if there were a 100 servers?

Comment: Create 100 instances of a class that differ by FTP settings. I would never create 100 differnt types!

Comment: so just keep passing in the connection settings required?

Answer (score 1):

Do the ftp servers have different interfaces? Or do they all understand the same set of commands you want to utilize already?

1. If so, then simply create one `FtpServer` class that accepts connection info. And create a `FtpClient` class that accepts multiple servers, that you can select by some key for instance. (At least this, to some extent, would probably be something I would do).

   ```
   class FtpClient
   {
       public function addServer( FtpServer $server, $key );

       public function selectServer( $key );

       public function putFileOnServer( $file );

       public function removeFileFromServer( $file );
   }
   ```
2. If not, and you have a class for each individual implementation already, that differ by their interfaces, for instance like:

   ```
   class FtpServerFoo
   {
       public function selectFile( $file );
       public function removeSelectedFile();
   }

   class FtpServerBar
   {
       public function removeFile( $file );
   }
   ```

   ... you should look into the [Adapter Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern):

   ```
   abstract class FtpServer
   {
       abstract public function putFile( $file );
       abstract public function removeFile( $file );
   }

   class FtpServerAdapterFoo
       extends FtpServer
   {
       public function __construct( FtpServerFoo $server )
       {
       }

       public function removeFile( $file )
       {
           $this->server->selectFile( $file );
           $this->server->removeSelectedFile();
       }
   }

   class FtpServerAdapterBar
       extends FtpServer
   {
       public function __construct( FtpServerBar $server )
       {
       }

       public function removeFile( $file )
       {
           $this->server->removeFile( $file );
       }
   }

   $cilent = new FtpClient();
   $client->addServer( new FtpServerAdapterFoo( new FtpServerFoo() ), 0 );
   $client->addServer( new FtpServerAdapterBar( new FtpServerBar() ), 1 );

   $client->selectServer( 0 );
   $client->putFileOnServer( $file );

   $client->selectServer( 1 );
   $client->removeFileFromServer( $someOtherfile );
   ```
3. If you don't have individual classes for differing FTP servers yet, then you can just implement the same interface (or inherit an abstract class) for each ftp server implementation and use the same type of FtpClient class as the one above again.

   Not really a facade pattern involved here though.

Answer (score 0):

You typically use facades to decrease complexity among multiple object types.  In this case, though, it appears you want to use only one functional "type", a "FTPServer".  For the most part, then, you should just have two instances of this type, and this type will have a "put" and "remove" method.

When you add needless function points, you actually increase the complexity of maintenance.  For instance, if you need to add a new parameter to your functions (maybe access restrictions or whatever), you not only have to change for each place of use, but now have to add in each facade method.  Abstraction should reduce this type of coupling, not increase it.

Comment: so have a facade for each ftp server?

Comment: No, facades don't seem to give you anything except added complexity here.  You are just adding methods without adding functionality.  That kind of duplication of existing duty only adds maintenance down the line.  Don't use facades at all here, because there is no reason.   Just use a normal everyday object.